# How to do cascade using hql query in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

How to do cascade save or update using hql query in hibernate? also how can i use cascade update for some specific fields instead of updating all child table fields?

for example table User has
**userName** varchar(10)
**Password** varchar(10)

table UserAccessRights has
**username** varchar(10) **FK of User table**
**password** varchar(10) **FK of User table**
Authpassword varchar(10)

cascade update should happen only for username not for password. how can i acheive this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit? A code example might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Since the cascade is a Hibernate configuration matter (i.e. HBM or annotations) the data must be returned to Java for processing of cascades.  Doing UPDATE/DELETE row modifications in HQL happens entirely on the SQL server (and the SQL server does not understand JPA cascades, as JPA is a Java API not an SQL API or SQL standard).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your cascade setting in your hbm files I suppose.

```
<set name="columnrecord" cascade="save-update" table="..."...>
      <key>
            <column name="COLUMN_NAME" not-null="true" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="..." />
</set>
```

Comment: This works with API like Session#save(Object) and Session#update(Object) but the question is about using HQL API like Session#createQuery(String).  Maybe you can cite a sample use of that API that makes use the cascade setting in the HBM XML fragment quoted.  I don't think you can but happy to be educated :)

Comment: Hi Darryl
If I write an HQL that manipulate an Entity, would not hibernate read its associated configuration (be it in hbm files or annotated entity classes) and perform the required cascade?

Comment: You misunderstand my point. The HQL runs as a statement on the server that can delete/destroy data entirely on the SQL server (bulk operations). In order for hibernate to know when to perform cascade it needs to know when the data values being destroyed are non-null.  Then perform additional SQL statement(s) to achieve the cascade operation. The point of me citing Session#save(), #delete() and #update() APIs etc.. is that the data is loaded into memory in Java allowing hibernate program control of bring into effect the 'cascade' setting. With data modifying HQL this is not possible.